# How to structure this application using node/express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm implementing an application that takes a file from a developer describing a UI with data bindings using a custom language I implement. My server takes the file (from a repo or directly) and creates a webpage (which implements the specified UI) that requests a .json (which specifies the data), which are served to the client. The server is responsible for, other than serving, keeping the data updated periodically from an exeternal SQL server. The application then allows the user to manipulate the data locally (think spreadsheet, with initial data from that SQL server).

I have the node part down (creation and maintenance of data structure), but I'm not sure how to serve the application itself. It will possibly have many scripts which will need to be served together. Do I place them directly in a HTML or .jade file to be served? Another option is to keep everything server-side and just have a UI which queries the data, but updates (via said user manipulation of data) are done in the server. This may make it lighter on the client, but I don't want to clog the server.

Would appreciate any help, let me know if anything needs clarification!

Comment: This problem doesn't really have anything to do with Node, right?  You're essentially asking how to structure a large amount of client-side code?  For what it's worth, I use Browserify for large projects like this.

Comment: @Brad Well, I wouldn't say doesn't have to do *anything* with node - one of my dilemmas is what to put on the server and what in the client served application. I will check out Browserify, thanks! BTW, how should I serve the html + script?

Comment: I think I got it, god I am so confused right now.

Comment: Ha, you've got it?  Or are confused?  What specifically are you confused about?  If possible, you can keep a lot of your application client-side and essentially provide an API to the server for persistent stuff.  That doesn't work well for all cases however.

Comment: I'm confused as to why I sat for half an hour trying to understand how to serve multiple files when it's something I did myself in express using `express.static` a week ago. Just overwhelmed :) Still not sure what to let the client and what to let the server do.

Comment: Why can't you use `express.static` now?  That's what I would do....